# Wordpress - Sorting post loop by meta data date

Tags: wordpress, sorting

I have two CPTs, one called 'artist' and the other called 'release.' I've created a single-artist.php page that displays an artist and its' custom meta data. On that same page I am displaying all releases by that artist with the following code:

```
<!-- GET RELEASES -->
<?php

$category = get_the_category();
$artist_name_slug = $category[0]->slug;

$args = array ('post_type' => 'release', 'posts_per_page' => 20, 'category_name' => $artist_name_slug);

query_posts ($args);

?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<h3 class="artist-col2-title">Releases</h3>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="artist-release"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail('small'); ?></a></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Within the release CPT I have a release date in the meta data.

I would like to sort the releases based on that date but I cannot figure out how to add that to my arguments. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the format that you are using for storing the date? I would assume that it's more or less a standard date format, which would make it unable for you to use a standard WordPress query to sort posts by a meta key. So you have two options: 1) custom SQL query(frowned upon, since it might not be forward-compatible); 2) using the published date for all of your "release" posts - is that a problem for you, instead of using a custom field?

Answer (score 0):

To sort by `meta data` you can use

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'release',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'category_name' => $artist_name_slug,
    'meta_key' => 'your_meta_key' // i.e. release_date
    'orderby'='meta_value' // for numeric value use 'meta_value_num' instead
);
query_posts ($args);
```

But notice the `meta_key` should be present in the query that you want to use for sorting, [see for more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).